# Make Nifty GUI ScreenController swallow input

Tags: java, slick2d, nifty-gui

In my Slick2D game, I'm extending `NiftyOverlayBasicGameState`, using Nifty GUI overlays, and specifying a `PlainSlickInputSystem`. For most overlaid screens I'd like Nifty GUI to ignore all input and pass it through to the `GameState`.

For one particular screen, I'd like to prevent all input getting through to the underlying `GameState` - but I only want this to happen for one screen, not all of them.

Is this possible using Nifty GUI, or am I taking the wrong approach? Can individual screens specify different input handling behaviour? Or should I instead be using a separate `GameState` with a different Niftyu GUI input system for the one screen where I want Nifty GUI to handle the input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several options available. The most basic one would be to have some sort of background layer and set `visibleToMouse="true"` for it. This way all of your mouse events will hit that layer and the mouse events will be marked as processed by **Nifty**. This should prevent the events from being forwarded to the `GameState`.